# php curl - long redirect time in curl_getinfo()

Tags: php, curl, performance

The code works, but it takes up to 10 seconds to load the page. Then I add curl_getinfo(), and discovered the redirect time has used 90% of the total time....

```
<?php
//
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/###";

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

$out = curl_exec($ch);

print "error:" . curl_error($ch) . "<br />";
print "output:" . $out . "<br /><br />";

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

curl_getinfo() shows:

```
Array ( 
[url] => http://www.somesite.com/xxx
[content_type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8 
[http_code] => 200 
[header_size] => 2760 
[request_size] => 5576 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 3 
[total_time] => 10.751595 
[namelookup_time] => 2.0E-5 
[connect_time] => 0.001612 
[pretransfer_time] => 0.001613 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 24506 
[speed_download] => 2279 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => 24506 
[upload_content_length] => 0 
[starttransfer_time] => 0.62479 
[redirect_time] => 9.080637 <--------------
[certinfo] => Array ( ) 
[redirect_url] => 
)
```

See `[redirect_time] => 9.080637` ?

It takes up 90% of the total time.

How to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME 
>   Pass a pointer to a double to receive the total time, in seconds, it took for all redirection steps include name lookup, connect, pretransfer and transfer before final transaction was started. CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME contains the complete execution time for multiple redirections. (Added in 7.9.7)

I say the most likely is the transfer fase: your *' http://www.somesite.com/xxx'* just being terribly slow (which is hard to fix if it isn't your site), 3 redirects taking > 3s each. But you could check how fast the dns lookup & connects are, seem ok though in that data.

Comment: But when I directly visit the http://www.somesite.com/xxx, it only needs less than 1 seconds!!!

Comment: Then examine the difference between the complete request in a browser & in a curl-session (complete request-headers & bodies, complete response-headers & bodies), twiddle with them until they are as much the same as you can get them. Logic dictates there is some difference now. I thought about keep-alive connections, but curl uses those by default...